# Changing UITableViewCell's default style's subviews' class

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6

I'm currently working on an update for my app. One of the new features I'm intending to add in requires me to replace the class of a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell`. However, I was previously using one of the default styles provided in Xcode for the cells, and the option to replace the class is disabled.

Is there any workaround for this without having to rewrite most of my code?

Answer (score 2):

To specifically do what you're asking, I would just change some classes around using some nifty Objective-C hacks.  Here's how:

1) Create a new UILabel subclass.  For this example, I'll use the class named `SwizzleLabel`.

2) Inside of this new label class, add a method to apply some styles to it (like changing the text color to what you'd like, etc).  This is basically a replacement for the init method.

```
-(void)applyStyles {

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

}
```

3) Import `<objc/runtime.h>` wherever you're going to be making this class change (for example, in your view controller, etc).

4) In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, create the `Class`.

```
Class newLabelClass = objc_getClass("SwizzleLabel");
```

5) Swap up the classes.

```
object_setClass([cell textLabel], newLabelClass);
```

6) Finally apply some custom styles that you have (basically a replacement for the init method).

```
[[cell textLabel] performSelector:@selector(applyStyles)];
```

Now, you should see that you've completely swapped out the label classes to your subclass.  My final `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method looked like so:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    Class newLabelClass = objc_getClass("SwizzleLabel");
    object_setClass([cell textLabel], newLabelClass);
    [[cell textLabel] performSelector:@selector(applyStyles)];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Testing"];

    return cell;

}
```